# https://mydomain/wp-admin redirects to wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

Whenever I enter https://mydomain/wp-admin while not being logged in, I get redirected to

```
wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fmydomain%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

With some help, I have created the following code to redirect users landing on the wp-login.php url to get forwarded to the desired custom page:

```
function redirect_wp_login_to_custom_login() {
    global $pagenow;
    $redirect_to;
    $current_url = home_url ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']); 

    if ('wp-login.php' == $pagenow) {
        if (!is_user_logged_in ()) 
            $redirect_to = get_home_url () . '/login/';
        else {
            if (is_super_admin() || is_admin())
                $redirect_to = get_home_url () .  '/wp-admin/';
            else
                $redirect_to = get_home_url () .  '/startseite/';
        }
        wp_safe_redirect ($redirect_to);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        global $wp;
        $login_url = get_home_url () . '/login/';
        if (!strcasecmp ($login_url, $current_url) && is_user_logged_in ()) {
            $redirect_to = get_home_url () . '/user-profile/';
            //wp_safe_redirect ($redirect_to);
        exit;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when entering proper user credentials and clicking the "log in" button in my custom login form, I seem to be getting forwarded to wp-login.php. This makes my above function redirect me to the custom login form, because apparently after clicking "log in" I am not yet logged in. How can I resolve this (apart from writing a custom login function that gets executed right after the "log in" button is clicked?)

Comment: This sounds like a plugin you have installed is doing something. Try disabling all of the plugins first.

Comment: No it's not. It is standard behavior of Wordpress.

Comment: You know what, my apologies, I misread the URL entirely and it didn't register that that was the default WP redirect URL.  Now that I'm reading this again, I actually have a custom built solution that I can provide if @Rodgath's answer below doesn't get what you need.  Again, sorry for the confusion from my original comment.

Comment: Hi Tony, absolutely no problem. I would be interested in seeing your solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to redirect to any page of your site by using the 'init' hook. Here's an example code to show how it can be done.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse388876_redirect_to_home_page');
function wpse388876_redirect_to_home_page() {
    
    global $pagenow;

    if ('wp-login.php' == $pagenow && (!is_user_logged_in() || !is_super_admin() || !is_admin())) {
        
        $redirect_to = home_url();
        
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);

        exit;
    }
}
```

All non-logged in users will be redirected but for logged-in users the super admin will not be redirected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just starting to dig into Wordpress' PHP interface, and this is very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. Remember you can change `home_url()` to the destination URL of your choice.

Comment: After trying your code, I found that it does not quite do what I want it to. Your condition (!logged in || !super admin || !admin) also seems to be faulty, because a super_admin is not an admin and vice versa, so that condition will always yield true as result. I have come up with some modified code, but it has its own problems. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: `is_super_admin()` is  usually used if you have WP multi-site installed. You can remove if you haven't installed WP Multi-site. Moreover, I should point out that the conditional `if ('wp-login.php' == $pagenow && (!is_user_logged_in() || !is_super_admin() || !is_admin())) {` I have used in the answer is just an example, you can edit and alter it depending on your project.

Comment: You may also try the code without the `if` conditional statement and see whether the redirection will work.